# Define style of image inside the append function

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image that I want to show on a div at the position of right click on the div. I am unable to do so maybe because I am adding the style in an incorrect manner. I am also seeing an error in the web console saying: "missing } after property list" on the line which I have shown below. Can anyone please help me with this. Here is the line in which I am trying to append the image to to div on the position of right click

```
$("#Boma").append($("<img>", {"src": "Boma.png" ,"style": width:25px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:xCoord; top:yCoord;}))
```

I have stored the right click coordinates in another function in xCoord and yCoord which are globally coordinates in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the string delimiters and the unit of measure in:

```
width:25px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:xCoord; top:yCoord;
```

```js
$("#Boma").append($("<img>", {
    "src": "Boma.png",
    "style": "width:25px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:" +
              xCoord + "px; top:" + yCoord + "px;"
}));
```

An example:

```js
var childLess = ['myTitle'];
var identifiedObjectsList = [];
$("#Boma").on('click', function (e) {
    var clickedItem = $(this).attr('title');
    if (childLess.indexOf(clickedItem) > -1) {
        var concept = clickedItem;
        identifiedObjectsList.push(concept);
        //console.log(identifiedObjectsList);
        $("#Boma").append($("<img>", {
            "src": "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff",
            "style": "width:25px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:" + 
             e.pageX + "px; top:" + e.pageY + "px;"
        }));
    }
});
```

```css
#Boma {
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Boma" title="myTitle"></div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the X/Y coords are JS variables, so you'll need to concatenate them to the string.

Comment: @gaetanoM I am able to see the image now but it sits at the side of the div and not over the div at the point of right click. Can you tell what could be the problem?

Comment: @Salman Answer updated. Let me know. Don't forget the **px** after e.pageX or y... Let me know Thanks

Comment: Thats it! That was missing. I added px and now I get want I wanted to see. Thanks a lot @gaetanoM

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can place the `style` in a single string, ensuring that you concatenate the variables correctly:

```
$('<img />', { 
  'src': 'Boma.png',
  'style': 'width: 25px; height: 20px; position: absolute; left: ' + xCoord + '; top: ' + yCoord + ';'
}).appendTo('#Boma');
```

Alternatively you can call the `css()` method separately on the `img` element you create:

```
$('<img />', { 'src': 'Boma.png' }).css({
  width: '25px',
  height: '20px',
  position: 'absolute',
  left: xCoord, 
  top: yCoord 
}).appendTo('#Boma');
```

As an aside, I'd strongly suggest you use classes for as much styling as possible. In your example it should be possible to make only the `top` and `left` rules inline.

Comment: I am able to see the image now but it sits at the side of the div and not over the div at the point of right click. Can you tell what could be the problem?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your HTML, but try placing `position: relative` in the CSS of `#Boma`. If that doesn't work, there's probably some issue with how you're getting the `xCoord` and `yCoord` values. I'd suggest starting a new question about it if that happens.

Comment: The web console shows me an error : "Error in parsing value for ‘left’.  Declaration dropped." and "Error in parsing value for ‘top’.  Declaration dropped."

Comment: That sounds like issues in the code you have not shown. If you double click those errors it should take you to the lines of code which caused the problem

Comment: Its pointing towards my html file and not the js file. It takes me to the jquery-ui v1.10.4 file, that I have added to my html file. Could it be that I have to add some other version other than 1.10.4. If not then what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: If the error is pointing there then you've probably passed an invalid argument to a jQuery method. Check the call stack to find the call in your own code which caused the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152452/discussion-between-salman-and-rory-mccrossan).